# Swift: Can I return a private type that implements a public class and conforms to a public protocol?

Tags: swift, inheritance, swift-protocols

In Objective-C, a function is able to return instances of a private type that implements a public class and public protocol without ever defining a public class that conforms to that protocol.

E.g. Let's say I have this header file:

```
@protocol Flyer <NSObject>
-(void) fly;
@end

@interface Animal : NSObject
-(void) eat;
@end

Animal<Flyer> * randomFlyingAnimal();
```

And this implementation file:

```
@implementation Animal

-(void) eat {
    NSLog(@"I'm eating");
}

@end

@interface Bird : Animal<Flyer>
@end

@implementation Bird

-(void) fly {
    NSLog(@"I'm a flying bird");
}

@end

@interface Bat : Animal<Flyer>
@end

@implementation Bat

-(void) fly {
    NSLog(@"I'm a flying bat");
}

@end

Animal<Flyer> * randomFlyingAnimal() {
    switch (arc4random() % 2) {
        case 0:
            return [[Bird alloc] init];
        case 1:
        default:
            return [[Bat alloc] init];
    }
}
```

In this example, the consumer of my code never actually knows about the `Bird` class or `Bat` class (or any other type that implements `Animal` and conforms to `Flyer`), but can be sure that the object that's returned from `randomFlyingAnimal` can both `eat` and `fly`.

Is such a thing possible in Swift?

Comment: Well asked question, but something you can simply try with minimal code conversion in a playground...

Comment: I've amended my question to be more clear to what I actually intended.I know in Swift if I was to publicly define a class that derived from Animal and conformed to Flyer, that I could return any private subclass of that type. However, I'm unsure what the signature of a method would be if no such public type existed that implemented Animal and conformed to Flyer.

Answer (score 0):

There a a few approaches which you could apply in Swift, but you would probably define a protocol `AnimalType` and a protocol `FlyerType` - which do not have a relation to each other:

```
public protocol AnimalType {}
public protocol FlyerType {
    func fly()
}
```

Then, create internal or private classes as follows:

```
internal class Animal: AnimalType {}
internal class Bird: Animal {}
internal class Bat: Animal {}
```

Now, class `Bird` and `Bat` conforms to `AnimalType` through inheriting form its base class `Animal`. In order to conform to `FlyerType` as well we could *extend*  these classes as follows:

```
extension Bird: FlyerType {
    internal func fly() { print("Bird's flying") }
}

extension Bat: FlyerType {
    internal func fly() { print("Bat's flying") }
}
```

Your factory function could then be implemented as below:

```
public func randomFlyingAnimal() -> protocol<AnimalType, FlyerType> {
    switch (arc4random() % 2) {
    case 0: return Bird()
    default: return Bat()
    }
}
```

`protocol<AnimalType, FlyerType>` is a [protocol composition type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID454) - whose application seems useful in this case.

Comment: This returns an object that conforms to a protocol that the Animal class conforms to. It doesn't actually return an Animal subclass.

The Objective-C ability is useful in the case where I want to return an object that derives from a class that I don't have access to amend, but allows me to ensure that it still conforms to my new protocol. E.g. I can return and store a pointer to a UIView *<MyCustomProtocol> and ANY type that both derives from UIView and conforms to MyCustomProtocol will do.

Comment: @guy Perhaps you can explain what's the difference is in returning an object that conforms both to `AnimalType` and `FlyerType` and returning an object that is derived from class Animal and conforms to `FlyerType`. Form the view point of a client, I don't see one - provided that protocol `AnimalType` exposes the same API as class `Animal`.